# Get all values from a JSON object and store in a flat array with Python

Tags: python, json

I am returning a JSON object from a requests call. I would like to get all the values from it and store them in a flat array.

My JSON object:

```
[
    {
        "link": "https://f.com/1"
    },
    {
        "link": "https://f.com/2"
    },
    {
        "link": "https://f.com/3"
    }
]
```

I would like to store this as:

```
[https://f.com/things/1, https://f.com/things/2, https://f.com/things/3]
```

My code is as follows.. it is just printing each link out:

```
    import requests
    import json

def start_urls_data():
    url = 'http://106309.n.com:3000/api/v1/product_urls?q%5Bcompany_in%5D%5B%5D=F'
    headers = {'X-Api-Key': '1', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    start_urls_data = json.loads(r.content)
    for i in start_urls_data:
        print i['link']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple list comprehension:

```
data = [
    {
        "link": "https://f.com/1"
    },
    {
        "link": "https://f.com/2"
    },
    {
        "link": "https://f.com/3"
    }
]

print([x["link"] for x in data])
```

This code just loops through the list `data` and put the value of the key `link` from the dict element to a new list.